# What is wrong with my pattern for preg_replace?

Tags: preg-replace

I have a variable containing the following html code

```
Bloom's:  Knowledge<br>  Difficulty: Medium<br>  Learning Objective: 01-03 <br>  Topic: Economic<br>
```

I want to use preg_replace to remove each of 'Bloom's:...' , 'Difficulty:....', 'Learning Objective:....', 'Topic:...'

I tried to match those terms but it doesn't work.

```
/Bloom's:.*<br>/ or /Difficulty:.*<br>
```

Can you show me the right way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but:

```
$whole_question = "Bloom's:  Knowledge<br>  Difficulty: Medium<br>  Learning Objective: 01-03 <br>  Topic: Economic<br>";

$removeKeys = array(
        'Bloom:',
        'Difficulty:',
        'Learning Objective:',
        'Topic:',
);

foreach ($removeKeys as $removeKey){
    $removeKey = '/'.$removeKey.'.*<br>/';
    $whole_question = preg_replace($removeKey,'<br>',$whole_question);
}
echo $whole_question;//Bloom's:  Knowledge<br>  <br>
```

Comment: Not clear enough. What is the final outcome you want ?